# One to many relation to one table causes an error in EF modeling

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a model in EF6 that contains several tables one of my tables is **ContentGrouptable** with this structure :

```
public partial class ContentGroup
{
    public ContentGroup()
    {
        this.Contents = new HashSet<Content>();
        this.ContentGroups = new HashSet<ContentGroup>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Visible { get; set; }
    public long Ordering { get; set; }
    public string CommentState { get; set; }
    public int ContentGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContentGroup> ContentGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentGroup ContentGroup1 { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see this table has a relation whit itself .**One to many on Id column**.It this table we have a **FK-ContentGroupId** that refers to itself(ContentGroup).So i create a view for this entity using MVC4(ASP) so when i want to insert a value to my table i got this error:

```
"Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may 
exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated 
values."
```

So what should i do ?it because of FK?

Best regards

Comment: I don't have experience with that. If it was me, I would just change the DB design, but despite that it seems that you need some kind of self-referencing `Entity`. I did a little research and got this tutorial - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code . Take a look and hope it helps.

Comment: You know i changed something based on your article that you said.after compile i got this error :Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ContentGroupId', table 'EducationDB.dbo.ContentGroups'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated..

Comment: So now i tried to set my column to allow nullable but i got this error:Error 1 Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ContentGroup' in relationship 'ContentGroupContentGroup'. Because all the properties in the Dependent Role are nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '0..1'.

Comment: I guess that having both `public int Id { get; set; }` and `public int ContentGroupId { get; set; }` is pretty confusing for `EF` because the convention for creating identity field is - looking for a property named `Id` or for property named - `<EntityName + Id>` and you have them both. First deal with that and then try to work it out step by step. Leave only `virtual ContentGroup ContentGroup1` or `virtual ICollection<ContentGroup> ContentGroups` and make it work with one of them then add the second self reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a non-nullable `ContentGroupId`. This means that when you insert a `ContentGroup`, you have to set its parent `ContentGroup` as well. But this a chicken and egg problem (or: no "valid ordering"). You can't insert a parent and child at the same time, it's always a sequential operation. And then, there must always be a "mother of all parents", not having a parent itself.

So, make `ContentGroupId` nullable and map the associations like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ContentGroup>()
    .HasOptional(cg => cg.ContentGroup1)
    .WithMany(cg => cg.ContentGroups)
    .HasForeignKey(cg => cg.ContentGroupId);
```